# How to properly use an observable with Redux store and routing

Tags: reactjs, redux, rxjs, react-router-redux, reselect

Using the [real-world example from Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/real-world), where would one best define an observable and then listeners on the *Redux* store?  For example from [this Redux discussion thread](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/227#issuecomment-119237073), when utilizing *redux-rx* where should the following code be placed in the *real-world* example?

```
const state$ = observableFromStore(store);

const didLogin$ = state$
    .distinctUntilChanged(state => !state.loggedIn && state.router.path === '/login')
    .filter(state => state.loggedIn && state.router.path === '/login');

didLogin$.subscribe({
    router.transitionTo('/success');
});
```

I was initially thinking that I would define this within containers/App.js but at that level the redux store is not available like it is in index.js and containers/Root.dev.js.  Perhaps utilizing React *context* somehow?  I am using a *reselect* selector for my `connect()` calls if that makes any difference.

Comment: Are you actually using React because the recommendations for react are to use connect() to wire up containers rather than using subscribe()?

Comment: @BrianShotola Yes, using React and the connect() calls just like that real-world example.  Just wanting to know where best to place code dealing with observables if you want to make one out of the Redux store. The store is defined in /index.js but that doesn't seem like the best place to deal with observables and listeners calling specific actions.

Comment: If you are using the React bindings provided by Redux, all of your component containers are subscribed to the store. When the store updates, your containers will get the new state in mapStateToProps(). This is your subscriber. That will then convert the state to props to pass to the actual React component. componentWillReceiveProps() will then get the props mapped in mapStateToProps().

Comment: @BrianShotola I'm following you mostly, but still uncertain where you're saying the observableFromStore() call should go.  Can you post an answer that explains?  Are you saying it should be placed in componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) { const state$ = observableFromStore(nextProps.someStateObject); ... }

Comment: I didn't catch that you are using redux-rx. I am unfamiliar with RxJS, but it appears to run by Microsoft and has no relationship to React.js. I don't understand why you would use RxJS with React.js If you truly have a Redux+React.js project, I don't think you need RxJS.